# Quote paragraphs replacing each other via fade in and out in a typewriter fashion

Tags: css, animation, fonts, fadein, fadeout

So there are two codes that I really want to combine because each one is missing an element of the other, and I have no clue how to. (Very VERY new to coding! :/)

The main goal is: upon opening my webpage, to be able to have a quote/paragraph* fade in by "typing itself" out in a typewriter-like fashion. After a short delay, it would fade out, and be replaced with a different quote typing itself out just as the first quote had, and so on, with many different quotes.

*I say "quote/paragraph" because I want to be able to have the quote typed out on more than one line it if is long - not just one long continuous line!

[Here](http://codepen.io/gavra/pen/tEpzn) is an example of what I wanted, but it's missing the fade in and fading out into another different text.

HTML:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Waiting+for+the+Sunrise"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<body>
<div id="typedtext"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', cursive; 
font-size:30px; 
margin: 10px 50px; 
letter-spacing: 6px; 
font-weight: bold;
}
```

JS:

```
// set up text to print, each item in array is new line
var aText = new Array(
"There are only 10 types of people in the world:", 
"Those who understand binary, and those who don't"
);
var iSpeed = 100; // time delay of print out
var iIndex = 0; // start printing array at this posision
var iArrLength = aText[0].length; // the length of the text array
var iScrollAt = 20; // start scrolling up at this many lines

var iTextPos = 0; // initialise text position
var sContents = ''; // initialise contents variable
var iRow; // initialise current row

function typewriter()
{
sContents =  ' ';
iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex-iScrollAt);
var destination = document.getElementById("typedtext");

while ( iRow < iIndex ) {
sContents += aText[iRow++] + '<br />';
}
destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) +      "_";
if ( iTextPos++ == iArrLength ) {
iTextPos = 0;
iIndex++;
if ( iIndex != aText.length ) {
iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length;
setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
}
} else {
setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed);
}
}


typewriter();
```

And then [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/) would be the simple (at least it looks simple?) fade in and out with different quotes that I envisioned.

HTML:

```
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.quotes {display: none;}
```

JS:

```
(function() {

var quotes = $(".quotes");
var quoteIndex = -1;

function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
}

showNextQuote();

})();
```

Also, I would ideally like to make changes to font size, color, style, etc., but the site i'm using only let's me input via HTML, so no CSS...(I have no idea if you can just somehow include CSS stuff directly into HTML or not...sorry I'm a dingus. :( ) This might be really easy, but I am no programmer - just someone with a vision. Any help you could provide would be incredibly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

this code only uses html and css https://codepen.io/rusjames/pen/uAFhE

```js
/* Inspired by Lea Verou's http://lea.verou.me/more-css-secrets/*/
```

```css
body{
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
} 

p{
  color: lime; 
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}

p:nth-child(2){
  animation: type2 8s steps(60, end);
}

p a{
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span{
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
} 

@keyframes type2{
  0%{width: 0;}
  50%{width: 0;}
  100%{ width: 100; } 
} 

@keyframes blink{
  to{opacity: .0;}
}

::selection{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<p>hi folks, this is typing animation using CSS</p>
<p>created with ♥ by 
  <a href="https://twitter.com/@samarkandiy" title="Azik Samarkandiy">@samarkandiy</a> 
:)<span>|</span></p>
```

Comment: Hi there! I saw this one while I was searching, and it was close to what I wanted, but like I said, I wanted the text to fade in, delay, then fade out, being replaced by different text. Also I am not sure how to incorporate CSS into HTML, or if that's even a thing, because the site I am using only allows HTML input.

Comment: You can use inline css in the html code.Look at this page for explanations http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: Alrighty - I know how to include css now - one problem solved, but still have the others to go...